# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A different version of script file has been loaded by debugged process

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I have strange behavior in VS 2012 with JavaScript as if it were caching old version. It appears to not load the latest changes made to the .js file when debugging. The breakpoint suggests

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A different version of this script file has been loaded by the debugged process. The script file may need to be reloaded."

Is there anyway to clear it out so that I can always run with latest changes? This only started happening recently (possible cause VS 2012 update 2???), I have used 2012 for months now and never had this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I have had the same problem when working with VS I just put a debugger; statement in the script where I want the page to break at.

Comment: Same here, i have to put in a debugger; statement to make it to break, after that i can set additional breakpoints (original breakpoints are lost). anybody an idea why that is the case? I guess it is still reading the wrong symbols?

Comment: I am still having this issue, even with the IE cache fix mentioned as an answer.

Comment: Had the same issue with VS2013, but the marked answer solved it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So it appears JavaScript files were getting cached in IE. The solution is it to go to IE > Internet Options > Settings (under browsing history) > Check for new version of stored pages : Every time I visit the webpage. Now every time I build/run debugger the most recent JavaScript file is loaded.

Comment: Also enable the option to always break on Javascript errors in IE. I had a scenario where my code did not break because of a closing curly not being placed....

Comment: With IE11: Internet Options > General Tab > Settings (under browsing history) > Check for new version of stored pages : Every time I visit the webpage. So it's on the General tab, just in case you'd search for Settings tab

Comment: Strangely, I didn't have this issue with VS2012, but when I switched to VS2015 it started. This solution works fine there as well.

Comment: Thanks. This wasted 2 hours of my time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the IE>Tools>Internet Options> Advanced Tab>
2. Uncheck the "Disable Script Debugging" option