# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded...." for javascript file in my ASP.NET webform app in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I am getting this message in my visual studio for my breakpoint only in my javascript file. The breakpoint works for the .cs files.

I tried the following, but didn't work:

The solution is it to go to IE > Internet Options > Settings (under browsing history) > Check for new version of stored pages : Every time I visit the webpage.

from

[The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A different version of script file has been loaded by debugged process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953930/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-a-different-version-of-script-file-has)

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: use the inspect element in the selected browser and breakpoint from there

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but have you tried setting this:

' Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
        ' visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = **False**

If set as true, JS breakpoints will not be hit.